# Foundation 6 - Dropdown panel - Connected area with button

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I need to make dropdown menu with connected area without border between button and dropdown-panel, but the borders at the edges of dropdown panel will be preserved. I use dropdown-pane from Foundation 6.

This is my result:
[image]

And this is my target:
[image]

Below is my HTML code where dropdown-wrapper is container for dropdown toggler and dropdown-panel. data-v-offset is set -1 to overlap border of item-container. I tried to set up the bottom border of item-container to background color, but dropdown-pane instantly overlap the item-container element.

```html
<ul class="bottom-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-wrapper" data-toggle="header-shopping-card" >
                                    <a href="#" class="item-container">
                                        
                                        <div class="item-content">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <span>Nákupní košík</span>
                                                <span class="box primary"><span>4</span></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-subtitle">12 000 Kč</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div
                                        class="dropdown-pane"
                                        id="header-shopping-card"
                                        data-dropdown data-hover="true"
                                        data-hover-pane="false"
                                        data-position="bottom"
                                        data-alignment="right"
                                        data-hover-delay=0
                                        data-v-offset=-1
                                    >
                                        Just some junk that needs to be said. Or not. Your choice.
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                
                            </ul>
```

And this is my SCSS code:

```css
.bottom-menu {
                    @include menu-base;
                    @include flex-align(right, middle);

                    .dropdown-wrapper {
                        border: 0;

                        &:hover {
                            .item-container {
                                background-color: $light-gray;
                                border: 1px solid $dark-gray;
                                border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;

                                .item-content {
                                    color: $black;
                                }

                                .item-subtitle {
                                    color: $dark-gray;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        .dropdown-pane {
                            background-color: $light-gray;
                            border: 1px solid $dark-gray;
                        }
                    }

                    .dropdown-pane {
                        font-size: $global-font-size;
                    }

                    .item-container {
                        transition-delay: 0;
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: flex-end;
                        font-size: $small-font-size;
                        border: 1px solid transparent;

                        .item-icon {
                            width: rem-calc(35px);
                            height: auto;
                            color: $accent-secondary;

                            .item-icon-path {
                                fill: $accent-secondary;
                            }

                            .item-icon-path-circle {
                                fill: $green;
                            }

                            .item-icon-path-check {
                                fill: $header-primary-color;
                            }
                        }

                        .item-content {
                            padding-left: 6px;
                            color: $header-primary-color;
                            font-size: rem-calc(12px);

                            .item-title {
                                margin-bottom: 4px;
                            }
                            .item-subtitle {
                                line-height: 1em;
                                color: $header-secondary-color;
                            }

                            .box {
                                display: inline-flex;
                                justify-content: center;
                                align-items: center;
                                min-width: rem-calc(21px);
                                min-height: rem-calc(21px);
                                color: $white;
                                font-size: rem-calc(13px);
                            }
                            .box.primary {
                                background-color: $primary-color;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know hot to remove border between dropdown-pane and item-container. Can you please help me? I'll be glad for every help.

Thank you,
Michal

Comment: You need to put all your code into a single snippet that reproduces the problem so people can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

`.item-container` must have `position: relative` and `.dropdown-pane` must have `position: absolute`. After that the `z-index` is working. Then Bottom border of the `.item-container` is overlapped by:

```css
.item-container:after {
                                content: '';
                                background-color: $light-gray;
                                position: absolute;
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 1px;
                                left: 0;
                                bottom: -1px;
                            }
```